# How do I make an enemy follow the player in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

So, I'm a beginner to Python and Pygame and would like some help. I'm trying to make a game similar to Asteroids and I've made most of this program by looking around at other examples on the internet. However, I'm stuck on this problem: how do I get an enemy sprite to follow the player sprite? I've googled how to do so and tried implementing the same thing on my code but the sprite just stays in one place and doesn't follow the player. I've used the vector stuff to create the player sprite and I still barely understand how that works. I'm sort of on a tight schedule so I don't have time to thoroughly understand this stuff but I intend to later. Sorry if I haven't explained my code properly but I'm still trying to understand how Pygame works and most of this code is basically just copied.

```
import random, math, pygame, time, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.math import Vector2



######Setting up Variables
class settings:
    fps = 30
    windowwidth = 590
    windowheight = 332

class ship:
    HEALTH = 3
    SPEED = 4
    SIZE = 25

class colours:
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    white = (255, 255, 255)

###########################




######################################################################################

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,image_file , pos=(0,0)):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (25,25))
        self.original_image = self.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.position = Vector2(pos)
        self.direction = Vector2(1, 0)
        self.speed = 0
        self.angle_speed = 0
        self.angle = 0

    def update(self):
        if self.angle_speed != 0:
            self.direction.rotate_ip(self.angle_speed)
            self.angle += self.angle_speed
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, -self.angle)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
        self.position += self.direction * self.speed
        self.rect.center = self.position

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, pos=(0,0)):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (25, 25))
        self.original_image = self.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.speed = 1

    def move_towards_player(self, Player):
        dx, dy = self.rect.x - Player.rect.x, self.rect.y - Player.rect.y
        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
        dx, dy = dx/dist, dy/dist
        self.rect.x += dx * self.speed
        self.rect.y += dy * self.speed







class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location





def main():
    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((settings.windowwidth, settings.windowheight))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Final Game')

    background = Background('space.jpg',[0,0])

    global player, enemy
    player = Player('SpaceShip.png',[200,100])
    playersprite = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain((player))
    enemy = Enemy('Enemy Hexagon.png',[300,150])
    enemysprite = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain((enemy))


    fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()


    intro = True

    while intro == True:
        myFont = pygame.font.SysFont('freesansbold.ttf', 75)
        otherFont = pygame.font.SysFont('freesansbold.ttf', 30)
        SurfaceFont = myFont.render("Space Destroyer", True, (colours.white))
        SurfaceFont2 = otherFont.render("Press Space to Start", True, (colours.white))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type ==    KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_SPACE:

                    intro= False

        screen.blit(SurfaceFont,(50,50))
        screen.blit(SurfaceFont2,(125,125))
        pygame.display.flip()
        screen.blit(background.image, background.rect)



    while intro == False:
        fpsClock.tick(settings.fps)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            enemy.rect.x
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    player.speed += 4
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    player.angle_speed = -4
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    player.angle_speed = 4

                if player.position.y < 0:
                    player.position = (player.position.x ,332)

                elif player.position.y > settings.windowheight:
                    player.position = (player.position.x, 0)

                elif player.position.x < 0:
                    player.position = (590, player.position.y)

                elif player.position.x > settings.windowwidth:
                    player.position = (0, player.position.y)

            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    player.angle_speed = 0
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    player.angle_speed = 0
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    player.speed = 0








        screen.fill(colours.white)
        screen.blit(background.image, background.rect)
        enemysprite.draw(screen)
        enemysprite.update()
        playersprite.draw(screen)
        playersprite.update()

        pygame.display.update()
        playersprite.update()

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never called `move_towards_player`. Try adding this:

```
...
enemysprite.draw(screen)
enemysprite.update()
playersprite.draw(screen)
playersprite.update()
enemy.move_towards_player(player)
...
```

Comment: Yeah, it did. Thank You.

Comment: ah, sorry new to this website

Comment: @RA Something else you may find helpful is https://codereview.stackexchange.com. It's meant for working code, and is a great place to learn best practices and more obscure features of programming languages.